# match until regex expression not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this regex that is supposed to match 1='aa' or 1="aa" or 1=aa, and return number/value.

```
(?<number>\d)=\s*("|')?\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=("|')?\d=|$)
```

it works but it is returning the value incorrectly. Number comes back as 1 but value as aa" in the case of 1="aa"

How can I get value = aa for the case of 1="aa".

Actual expression may contain 1='aa' 2="bb" 3=cc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that this:

```
(?=("|')?\d=|$)
```

means "followed by any of the following:

- `"` plus a digit plus `=`
- `'` plus a digit plus `=`
- a digit plus `=`
- end-of-string

". You'll notice that it does *not* make any allowance for whitespace between the `"` or `'` and the digit; so in the case of `1="aa" 2=...`, the `value` simply is not *allowed* to be followed by `" 2=...`. Similarly, it does *not* make any allowance for `"` or `'` plus end-of-string.

So the minimal fix is to allow — nay, *require* — some whitespace before the digit, and to move the `("|')?` out of the lookahead assertion and into the main part of the regex:

```
("|')?(?=\s+\d=|$)
```

giving:

```
(?<number>\d)=\s*("|')?\s*(?<value>.*?)("|')?(?=\s+\d=|$)
```

While we're at it, we might as well make some other tweaks to simplify the regex and reduce the number of cases where it can go wrong:

```
(?<number>\d)=\s*(["']?)(?<value>.*?)\1(?=\s+\d=|$)
```

(Further cleanup may be possible, but I don't know enough about your data to recommend any more changes.)

Comment: Thank you. It is working correctly. When you copy from SO, it also copies a new line and so it wasnt working correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. The easiest and readable way to match exactly pair of quote symbols (which are the same, e.g. not like there: `1='aa"`)  is the following:

```
(
 (
  (?P<number>\d)="(?P<value>[^"]+)"     #or * in stead of + if value can be empty
 ) |
 (
  (?P<number>\d)='(?P<value>[^']+)'     #or * in stead of + if value can be empty
 ) |
 (
  (?P<number>\d)=(?P<value>[^\s]+)      #here you should also choose where you stop 
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(?<number>\d)=\s*("|')?\s*(?<value>.+?)("|')?(\s|$)
```

It will work, if an assignment is followed by either a space or a line-end.

Comment: I edited my answer, as my previous solution only worked for single assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Other items to consider:

- Your original expression (but not your example) seems to be intended to support whitespace near the equals sign.
- Does your number need to support multiple digits?
- Using square brackets for optional characters can avoid unnecessary capture groups

  (?<number>\d+)\s*=\s*["']?(?<value>[^"'\s]+)["']?